# What are some resources for interacting with C from C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, interaction

I'm currently developing a SDK for our product in C++. However, some of our customers have a code base written in C that will need to interface with our SDK. I need to provide C Interfaces and am looking for some references on how best to approach this.

I'm using the GNU compilers (version 4.6.3).

I am aware of the extern "C" {} construct and have used it sparingly, but I'm not really an expert with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Provide some C language interfaces or functions that use static C++
   objects to invoke functionality.
2. Add static functions to your classes for use with the C language.
3. Change your design so that there are free standing functions that
   accept structures and classes.
4. Also, don't overload free standing functions.